# dplyr mutuate add new column value only once a different column == specific value

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with the following structure (summary example, not actual)

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(MedID = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 
222, 222, 222), Service = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Acute care", "Ext care", "Outpt 
care"), class = "factor"), AdmitDate = structure(c(16832, 16861, 
16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17181, 17212, 17240, 17271, 17301), class 
= "Date"), Flag = c(0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = 
c("MedID", "Service", "AdmitDate", "Flag"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
class = "data.frame")
> df1
    MedID  Service   AdmitDate  Flag
1    111 Acute care 2016-02-01    0
2    111 Acute care 2016-03-01    0
3    111   Ext care 2016-04-01   99
4    111 Acute care 2016-05-01    0
5    111 Acute care 2016-06-01    0
6    111 Outpt care 2016-07-01    0
7    222 Outpt care 2017-01-15    0
8    222   Ext care 2017-02-15   99
9    222 Acute care 2017-03-15    0
10   222 Acute care 2017-04-15    0
11   222 Outpt care 2017-05-15    0
```

I wish to use dplyr, group_by(MedID) and mutate to add a column in a new dataframe (let's call it Flag2 in df2) such that within each patient (MedID) the df2$Flag2 column == 1 *for every subsequent row within that unique MedID* but only after the df1$Flag column == 99, otherwise the df2$Flag2 column gets a 0. I can code this as desired if df1$Flag == 99 in the first row of a MedID, but otherwise my code either produces 1 in df2$Flag2 only in the row where df1$Flag == 99, *or* it produces a 1 for all rows in a given MedID where df1$Flag == 99. The desired output is:

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(MedID = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 
222, 222, 222), Service = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Acute care", "Ext care", "Outpt 
care"), class = "factor"), AdmitDate = structure(c(16832, 16861, 
16892,16922, 16953, 16983, 17181, 17212, 17240, 17271, 17301), class 
= "Date"),Flag = c(0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99, 0, 0, 0), Flag2 = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("MedID", "Service", 
"AdmitDate", "Flag", "Flag2"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = 
"data.frame")
> df2
    MedID    Service  AdmitDate Flag Flag2
1    111 Acute care 2016-02-01    0     0
2    111 Acute care 2016-03-01    0     0
3    111   Ext care 2016-04-01   99     1
4    111 Acute care 2016-05-01    0     1
5    111 Acute care 2016-06-01    0     1
6    111 Outpt care 2016-07-01    0     1
7    222 Outpt care 2017-01-15    0     0
8    222   Ext care 2017-02-15   99     1
9    222 Acute care 2017-03-15    0     1
10   222 Acute care 2017-04-15    0     1
11   222 Outpt care 2017-05-15    0     1
```

Here is a snipit example of the code, but not complete since it does not execute properly... Do I need to nest the mutate within a For loop, that seems like mingled R coding? :( Note: df1$Flag can only == 99 once per MedID, which I think should make it easier.

```
`df2 <- df1 %>% `
    `group_by(MedID) %>%`
    `mutate(Flag2 = ifelse(df1$Flag == 99, 1, 0))`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be using `fill` from `tidyr`. The approach would be to first add `Flag2` and assign as `1` for rows having `Flag == 99` otherwise `NA`.

Now fill rows downwards in `Flag2` column. Finally replace all `NA` with 0.

```
  library(tidyverse)
  df1 %>%
  group_by(MedID) %>%
  mutate(Flag2 = ifelse(Flag == 99, 1L, NA)) %>%
    fill(Flag2) %>%
    mutate(Flag2 = ifelse(is.na(Flag2), 0L, Flag2))
```

Though `OP` has not mentioned it but if `AdmitDate` is expected to decide which row comes after matching `Flag == 99` then arrange should be added in above code.

```
  df1 %>%
  group_by(MedID) %>%
  mutate(Flag2 = ifelse(Flag == 99, 1L, NA)) %>%
  arrange(AdmitDate) %>%
    fill(Flag2) %>%
    mutate(Flag2 = ifelse(is.na(Flag2), 0L, Flag2))
```

Comment: Hell yes! Nice work, and thanks for the quick and accurate reply. I was stuck on this for a few hours. Appreciate the expertise.

Comment: @user3885754 Good to know it worked for you. You can do 2 things. Please `dput` on your example dataframe and add output of that to your question. It will be easier for others to follow your question. Secondly if answer worked for you than you can accept it by clicking `tick` in left of answer-box.

Comment: Updated as per stackoverflow convention